# rewrite all urls that start with..,

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite

I want to rewrite the following url:

```
 http://localhost/albums/album_name/22
```

to:

```
http://localhost/album.php?id=22
```

I want only urls starting with /albums/ to be rewritten. I tried this, but it doesn't work.

```
RewriteRule /albums/^[^/]+/([\d]+)$ /album.php?gallery_id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I thinks you can't use `\d` inside the `[..]` brackets. Try `RewriteRule /albums/^[^/]+/([0-9]+)$ /album.php?gallery_id=$1 [L]` instead. Also don't forget to add a `RewriteEngine On` and maybe a `RewriteBase /`.

Comment: Still the same. I have that before

Comment: What happens when you load `http://localhost/albums/album_name/22`. Do you get a 404-Not found?

Comment: Is htaccess enabled? Try putting some junk text into the htaccess and see if you get a 500 error.

Comment: it's enabled. I tried another rule and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a `^` that is in the wrong location (how did I miss that???)

```
RewriteRule ^albums/[^/]+/([\d]+)$ /album.php?gallery_id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: I would keep the `^`, but the leading `/`, indeed, shouldn't be there. See edit above